# Can relational algebra/calculus proofs be used to test/verify SQL?

Tags: testing, sql, math, relational-database

Is it feasible or even possible to use relational algebra and/or relational calculus in the form of proofs to test/verify the correctness of SQL statements, functions, and stored procedures?

It seems to me like it should be at least possible, but I don't know if there's a detail I'm missing that makes a 1:1 mapping between the proof and the code incorrect.

Have any of you tried a method like this? Did it work? What were your experiences like?

Comment: Please repeat after me: SQL is not relational.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some known mapping rules between relational algebra operators and SQL statements. For example, the Sigma operator maps to a SELECT statement, there's a one-to-one mapping for the join operators, Delta maps to selecting a subset of columns, etc.

> Is it possible to use relational algebra to verify the correctness of SQL statements?

Yes, it is possible. Of course you'll need to have a clear schema of the database with all the relationships, foreign keys, etc. In some cases it's even easier to manipulate relational algebra statements than SQL statements (there are proven [transformation rules](http://www.cs.xu.edu/csci335/08f/Assignments/equivalenceRules.pdf) for modifying and simplifying statements).

But on the other hand, I don't think that verifying statements using relational algebra is much easier than testing SQL statements, especially when you have a database ready where you can execute the queries and see the results.

Comment: Just wanted to say: Relational operators map to "SELECT DISTINCT" since relational algebra uses sets of tuples and therefore cannot handle duplicates. The sigma itself corresponds to the WHERE-clause, the pi to the SELECT and so on.

Comment: The join operators are not 1:1, the SQL versions treat nulls specially, and similarly predicates are not Boolean.